# Benchmark problems for combinatorial multi-objective optimisation

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, online-resources, benchmark, multi-objective-optimization

Does anyone know of any good benchmark problems for combinatorial multi-objective optimisation? Something where pareto frontiers are known for example would be very useful.

Answer (score 9):

[vOptLib](https://voptsolver.github.io/vOptLib/): Library of numerical instances for MultiObjective Linear Optimization problems

From the site:

> vOptLib (short for vector optimization library) is a collection
>   problem instances for benchmarking multi-objective solvers. It covers
>   a variety of Multiobjective linear optimization problems
>   (multiobjective combinatorial problems, multiobjective integer linear
>   programs, multiobjective mixed integer programs).

Comment: This looks great, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There is also the *[MOrepo](https://github.com/MCDMSociety/MOrepo)* maintained by [Lars Relund Nielsen](https://www.research.relund.dk/). MOrepo describe itself as:

*This repository is a response to the needs of researchers from the MCDM society to access multi-objective (MO) optimization instances. The repository contains instances, results, generators etc. for different MO problems and is continuously updated. The repository can be used as a test set for testing new algorithms, validating existing results and for reproducibility. All researchers within MO optimization are welcome to contribute.*

*The repository consists of a main repository MOrepo at GitHub and a set of sub-repositories, one for each contribution. Sub-repositories are named MOrepo- where name normally is the surname of the first author and year of the study. All repositories are located within the MCDMSociety organization at GitHub.*

*The main repository contains documentation about how to use and contribute to MOrepo. Moreover, a set of tools are given in the R package MOrepoTools which can be used to retrieve info about test instance groups, results and problem classes.*